# R Notebook: One script, multiple HTML pages

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown, rnotebook

I have a single R Notebook script that produces a lot of figures and I'd like to have it render as several navigable pages (rather than one long document with anchor tags). For example, a title page with clickable links. I could do this – and have in the past – by breaking my script into several different scripts that produce individual HTML files, and then creating a master page that links to them. This solves the problem, but is somewhat clunky as the different pages are essentially the same output just for different cases so it doesn't make sense to split the source file up. I think this is possible using Bookdown, as that breaks stuff up into separate chapters with a table of contents. Nevertheless, I think this would mean sacrificing some Notebook features. Is there a way to use R Notebook to achieve a similar result?